# How do I click a submenu in an accordian menu using protractor javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I'm working in protractor cucumber framework and facing below issue.

I have a main menu and many submenus poping below if the main menu is clicked or hovered.
Currently i am able to click the main menu, but unable to click the submenu since it vanishes so quickly.

Below is my current code snippet

```
return this.elements.mainMenu.isDisplayed()
                .then((visible) => {
                    if (visible) {
                        this.elements.mainMenu.click().then
                            (() => {
                                this.elements.subMenu.isDisplayed()
                                    .then((visible) => {
                                        if (visible) {
                                            this.elements.subMenu.click().then
                                                (() => {
                                                    console.log('Clicked sub menu');
                                                });
                                        }
                                    });

                            });
                    }
                });
```

mainMenu and subMenu are already predefined elements in my class.
The log even prints 'Clicked sub menu'.
Assertion fails since I will verify the url of the submenu.But it shows the url of the main menu.

Comment: are you sure that it was not clicked? or the page hasn't loaded yet before the validation?

Comment: Do you have an example code or something? And I agree with @PaulCo, are you sure you have clicked the item? To be sure add a `browser.sleep(3000)` in the `then` after clicking on the mainmenu. What could also help is [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/website/test/e2e/navigation_spec.js). This is the specfile from protractor itself to test their menu of their own website. Hope it helps

Comment: Make use of actions class to get to submenu items